# How to speed up data transfer between nodes to my Elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

Usually my ES cluster has three nodes, one primary and two replicas. With every new deployment we move ES data to the new ES cluster by changing Elasticsearch configuration and add the new three nodes:

```
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["HOSTNAME1", "HOSTNAME2", "HOSTNAME3","NEW_HOSTNAME4", "NEW_HOSTNAME5", "NEW_HOSTNAME6"]
```

Data is replicated and splited between nodes and then exclude the old nodes with the API call:

```
"cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._ip" : "IP_HOSTNAME1,IP_HOSTNAME2,IP_HOSTNAME3"
```

And finally ALL data is moved on the new nodes, old ES cluster is destroyed and deployment is done.
The Issue is that data is growing fast and the process is taking longer to replicate and move data between ES nodes. We wait like 1hour and 30min for ~200GB of data to be moved.
Is there some fine tuning for ES to speed up data transfer between nodes?

We have this process because the AMI/OS for the ES nodes needs to be updated with the new security implementations every month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to reduce the time by helf, setting:

```
ccr.indices.recovery.max_bytes_per_sec
```

to 200Mb depending on the instance resources. For more advanced settings on cluster transfer please check ccr.indices.recovery.max_bytes_per_sec.

Answer (score 1):

If every shard in the cluster is replicated, I'd suggest just adding new nodes based on the new AMI in the cluster, and then removing old nodes.

Note that you should wait for all shards to be assigned before removing any node (i.e. cluster state is "green"). Remove nodes one by one, and wait for the cluster state change to green in between.

This procedure should be easy to automatize.

If not all shards have replicas, you can either:

- Setup replicas=1 for these indices, and after finishing "refreshing" the nodes, set up replicas=0 again.
- Tell the cluster to stop routing shards to the nodes being removed:

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
"transient" : {
"cluster.routing.allocation.include._ip " : "<ip of the node>"
}
}
```

For more information, see: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.14/modules-cluster.html#cluster-shard-allocation-filtering

I think that this last method is the best, either if you have or not replica shards.

Comment: Yes, from the replication point of view this is the procedure, but I thought there is an API call or some workaround to increase the replication data transfer when adding new nodes and remove the old ones.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with that.